# Retain Formatting when using get_the_content

Tags: wordpress

i am using this code to trim Words for a page

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40 ); ?>
```

it is removing all the HTML tags is there a way to retain all the formatting or some other function that can do the job. ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you use

```
$new_content = substr ( get_the_content() , 0, 40 );
echo $new_content;
```

I hope this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need excerpts on pages? If so, you could put this in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

Install: [Advanced Excerpt](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/), there you can select what stuff the advanced excerpt can poop out. And you can use the function in your template files, ie. like this:

```
<?php the_advanced_excerpt('length=150'); ?>
```

If you don't want to use a plugin checkout this [link](http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/).